# Positioning one div next to others

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is probably is a stupid question but im pretty new to Bootstrap and dont know which is the proper way to fix the following:

I have 5 divs one bellow other ( filled with a pink color ) and another div (filled with a yellow color). There is also a     `<hr/>` line which starts after the div no:5.
[image: Like showed on the picture]

What i want to do is to place the yellow div right from the pink ones like on the image bellow:[image]
 I have tried to add the yellow div with the length of `col-md-10` inside the first row, but it doesnt look like i wanted.

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/sJkZNxs07P).

Any help is appreciated. 
Keep in mind that everything needs to be responsive.

Comment: Like this? http://www.bootply.com/MVVWFwJm8a

Comment: @error404 Thanks for your replay, it is way better solution. However when i re-size the window all of the pink div's are covered with the yellow div. Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: Check the values for col-sm etc. on the yellow column http://www.bootply.com/gQxDmu3opF I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much ! My reputation dont allow me to vote up your answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use or rows is causing this issue. Combine your `box`'s in to a column: [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/gQxDmu3opF)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
        <div class="box text-center">1</div>
        <div class="box text-center">2</div>
        <div class="box text-center">3</div>
        <div class="box text-center">4</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-9 col-sm-10 yellow">  YeLLoW ? </div> 

  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all lef divs in a .col-md-2 container and the yellow part as you have it, something like

```
     <div class="col-md-2 box col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
       <div class="pink">div 1</div>
       <div class="pink">div 2</div>
       <div class="pink">div 3</div>
       <div class="pink">div 4</div>
       <div class="pink">div 5</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 box col-xs-9 col-sm-10">
       <div class="yellow">yellow part</div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but when i re-size the window all divs with pink color are disappearing. Do u know how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Your classes are handling the resized layout, nothing really disappears. Have you tried on bootly or in a normal page you made? because bootly says "Bootstrap Editor use requires a larger screen resolution... " at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the "XS" measure because of, bootstrap is used for mobile first, so that the first measure to take account is the "xs" one and the rest depends on this. I mean that if you put col-xs-12 only, the result for responsive is the same if you put "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12, col-lg-12".

For that reason if you want to have the same view as in larger sizes as in smaller sizes you can use like this:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
        <div class="box text-center">1</div>
        <div class="box text-center">2</div>
        <div class="box text-center">3</div>
        <div class="box text-center">4</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-10 yellow">  YeLLoW ? </div>    
  </div>
  <hr>

</div>
```